# Syntax confusion, Babel error or have I just been using this wrong

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I typically develop react applications, and as such I'm spoiled with all of the preset configurations that it comes with for babel. I set babel up myself for a new project and started testing all of the features I wanted to use, one of the things that I do is use `export default` quite a bit, however I ran into a not-so-familliar error.

`export default cache = new Cache()`

gives me the following code

`exports.default = cache = new Cache()`

Which of-course, is a syntax error. I had to cross verify that I've been doing this in my react applications, and I have been without any problems, so the code that I have to use now with my current setup is as follows:

`export default new Cache()` which makes sense, but also seems much less clean.

I'm just wondering if this is a babel setting that I've missed, or if I've been getting away with using improper syntax this entire time.

Comment: *"Which of-course, is a syntax error."* - Is it? Looks like valid syntax to me. If `exports` is an object and `Cache()` is a function it should run without error. What specifically seems invalid to you?

Comment: The fact that the value `cache` doesn't exist.  So, assigning `exports.default = cache` is an error, as `cache` doesn't exist anywhere. Thus causing the application to crash on init.

Comment: That's not a *syntax* error. I guess in strict mode it would be a *reference* error.  Note that the `cache = new Cache()` part happens *before* the `exports.default = cache` part, so in non-strict mode if `cache` wasn't previously declared that line would create it as a global and then both `cache` and `exports.default` would refer to the same object. When you run the code, what error message do you get?